# Want to designate project as shared vpc project and also want other project to communicate with it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc

I am working in a google cloud platform(GCP). My aim is to create a shared vpc project that will be a host project and wants the other two projects to communicate with it so i have three projects with me. Now I entered into the shared project which want to be a host project, so i entered into the shared vpc network panel and i press `setup shared vpc` it display error `You don't have permissions to perform the action on the selected resource.` I am login as `ayush` user-id i and i already gave myself different permission like `Owner, Serverless VPC Access Admin, Serverless VPC Access User, Serverless VPC Access Viewer` but still not working. Is there any other information that i can provide then please ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to security issues it seems that in order to be able to set-up a Shared VPC host project you need to have organization level roles, project level roles are not enough. Have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#prepare_your_organization) at the kind of permission that you need.

In order to get that permission you need the organization admin to grant you the adequate permissions.

> An Organization Admin can grant one or more IAM members the Shared VPC Admin and Project IAM Admin roles. The Project IAM Admin role grants Shared VPC Admins permission to share all existing and future subnets, not just individual subnets. This grant creates a binding at the organization or folder level, not the project level. So the IAM members must be defined in the organization, not just a project therein.

You can find more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#nominating_shared_vpc_admins_for_the_organization).